# Can I debug my applications on my phone without root?

Tags: android

I recently screwed up and installed an OEM update without thinking it would cause me to lose root. Sadly, my phone isn't popular enough for the root for this SW version to be out...

So then, can I still deploy applications to my phone?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes of course. See [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/device.html) for details.

Answer (score 3):

It should work without a hitch, as long as you enable USB Debugging

Settings->Applications->Development->USB Debugging checked

and Unknown sources from Settings->Applications->Unkonw Sources checked

You don't need root or anything else.

Best of luck to you developing!

Answer (score 2):

Are you talking about debugging via eclipse?  You should just be able to set the option USB debug (Settings->Applications->Development->USB debugging) and then you should be able to directly access the device from adb.

If you want to just send yourself the apk and install it on the device then you would want option Unknown sources(Settings->Applications->Unknown sources).

for more info check out the Google article on the [adb](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/adb.html)

Answer (score 2):

You can use non-rooted Android for development purposes.

Just go to `phone settings / applications` and you need to allow Uknown sources and in the development submenu allow debug via USB

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, adb tool is able to install .apk package without root permissions. See http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/adb.html (adb install command). If you are using Eclipse, it also installs packages without root permissions. I don't have root permissions on my tablet PC, but still can install, uninstall and debug applications.